# Filter object with multiple string values

Tags: reactjs, filter, autosuggest

I'm trying to filter an object with the elements that match the string that the user writes on the input. I'm using autosuggest to render the suggestions.
This is what i have so far:

```
<Autosuggest
                  suggestions={options}
                  onSuggestionsFetchRequested={fetchOptions}
                  onSuggestionsClearRequested={() => setOptions([])}
                  getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
                  renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
                  inputProps={inputProps}
                />
```

I have all the options on a prop and i want to filter those options to show the ones matching the input, this is how i'm filtering right now:

```
const fetchOptions = async ({ value }) => {
    setSelected(null);

    value = value.toLowerCase();
    const results = props.completeOptions.filter(
      (v) => v.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) != -1
    );
    setOptions(limit(results)); //Here i'm setting the options hook that i use on the suggestions
  };
```

This is the value of completeOptions prop that i have on redux:

```
[
        {
            "id": "1",
            "label": "33 Red Case"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "label": "Blue Case"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "label": "1 Green Case"
        },
        ...
]
```

Now, this is working perfectly if i input for example "Case" (this shows the 3 labels), if i use "33" (shows the first one), but if i input "33 case" doesn't show anything and it should show the first option.

How can i solve this? Is it convenient to split the value and search each one, is it better to search the whole string together?

Comment: [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and similar string matchers are not "fuzzy", they are looking for an exact match to your string including whitespace. In your example, "33 case" has no matches in `completeOptions` because the only potential match has other content between "33" and "case". Splitting the value is an option, or use a regex-based matcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for full search word match. You can use `every` in `javascript` to check search word and return true when all the search word get a match. You can check this code.

```
const searchData = value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
const results = props.completeOptions.filter(v => searchData.every(word => v.label.toLowerCase().includes(word)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter logic looks fine, when we just want a check whether substring is present then we should go with
`v.label.toLowerCase().split(" ").includes(value)`

Or

`v.label.toLowerCase().split(" ").some(val => val.includes(value)`

In above case we are splitting string to array and matching substring with each of token

`indexOf` handles substring checking little different and can cause undesired results.